# Shapiro.test error message: attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Tags: r

I am attempting to perform a test for normality in some stock returns, both visually and with a test. I think I got it right with the histogram, but the Shapiro test is giving me the following error message:

Error in .xts(e, .index(e2), .indexCLASS = indexClass(e2), .indexFORMAT = indexFormat(e2), : attempt to set an attribute on NULL

I attempted to make the following code reproducible, but please let me know if theres anything else needed.

```
library(quantmod)

DNB = getSymbols("DNB.OL", src = 'yahoo', 
           from = "2020-01-01",
           to = "2020-12-31")

DNBclose <- DNB.OL$DNB.OL.Close
DNBreturn <- dailyReturn(DNBclose, type = "log", leading = "FALSE")

std <- sqrt(var(DNBreturn, na.rm = TRUE))
DNBmean <- mean(DNBreturn, na.rm = TRUE)

DNBhist <- hist(DNBreturn, density=20, breaks=20, prob=TRUE, 
     xlab="x-variable", ylim=c(0, 35), 
     main="normal curve over histogram")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean=DNBmean, sd=std), 
      col="darkblue", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
 
shapiro.test(DNBreturn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?shapiro.test`, input 'x'

> x - a numeric vector of data values. Missing values are allowed, but the number of non-missing values must be between 3 and 5000.

Here, we have a an 'xts' object which basically inherits a `matrix` class as well.  So, we can either convert to `vector` by using `as.numeric` or `as.vector`

```
shapiro.test(as.numeric(DNBreturn))

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  as.numeric(DNBreturn)
W = 0.93466, p-value = 4.172e-09
```

---

Or call the `matrix` again to remove the `xts` class

```
shapiro.test(matrix(DNBreturn))
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  matrix(DNBreturn)
W = 0.93466, p-value = 4.172e-09
```

---

Or may change the `class` by assignment

```
class(DNBreturn) <- "matrix"
shapiro.test(DNBreturn)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  DNBreturn
W = 0.93466, p-value = 4.172e-09
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer of @akrun, that the `xts`object needss to be converted in something simpler, one should also know that Shapiro test is often less useful than expected. This is surely a case for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) where one can find lots of related posts, e.g. ["Is normality testing 'essentially useless'"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)? It is of course not completely useless, but it is often better to understand patterns and reasons of normality departures, e.g. with a graphical method. A histogram as was used by the OP or a quantile-quantile plot can be very helpful, e.g.:

```
x <- as.vector(DNBreturn)
shapiro.test(x)
qqnorm(x)
qqline(x)
```

More about this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).